# Given a string, return true if the first instance of "w" in the string is immediately followed by another "w"

Tags: java

Given a string, return true if the first instance of "w" in the string is immediately followed by another "w".

doubleX("awwbb") → true

doubleX("awawaw") → false

doubleX("wwwww") → true

I have tried three ways to this question, and all of the codes run, but it can't pass the test: wawww should return true, but my code shows false.

I was wondering what part of my thinking is wrong. Thank you very much!

My solution 1:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    if (str.substring(i, i+2).equals("ww")){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

My solution 2:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    if (str.charAt(i)== 'w' && str.charAt(i+1)== 'w'){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

My solution 3:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'w'){
      if (str.charAt(i+1) == 'w'){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `wawww should return true, but my code shows false.` Why? Given your description of how this algorithm should work, this _should_ return false.

Comment: Given "return true if the _first instance of 'w'_ in the string is immediately followed by another 'w'." you should return `false` for "wawww" because the first 'w' is a single occurence. All of your solutions seem to ignore the "first" portion of the task and return `true` if there is _any_ occurence of "ww". Btw, solutions 2 and 3 are essentially the same.

Comment: A) why are giving us 3 different solutions here? This isn't a free tutoring service where people sit down with you to look over all your efforts to then discuss which one is wrong for what reason B) for most of it, think about **reversing** your return statements. Meaning: after you checked the first `w` character, you absolutely know: I should return true or false. There is no point checking **other** later `w` chars. As according to your description, only the first one matters!

Comment: You need to test specifically with the first `w` found. Your code is just looking for a `w` followed by another, which will return false only in a string that does not have `ww`. Better use something like `return str.charAt(str.indexOf('w') + 1) == 'w'` (after testing that the length will not cause a string index out of bounds)

Comment: In `wawww` first occurrence of `w` is followed by `a`, so `False` should be returned.

Comment: all you should do is indexOf("w") and indexOf("ww") and compare those

Comment: @Stultuske as long as both do not return `-1`

Comment: Be careful. If neither are found, they'd be result in `-1`, which would equal and return true if you don't check for that.

Comment: that is quite easily tested for. Either way, it still only requires those two actions to find the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is better to find the index of the first 'w' and then check if the letter to its right is also a 'w'.
You code should look something like this:

```
static boolean doubleX(String str) {
    int i = str.indexOf('w');
    return i > -1 && i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'w';
}
```

Explanation:

Your requirement says that you need to check if there is a 'w' next to the first occurrence of 'w', hence, you don't have to check for the existence of 'ww' anywhere in your string.

The first part of the return statement `i > -1` checks if there exists a 'w' in your string, then `i + 1 < str.length()` checks if the 'w' that was found, is not on the last position (because if it would be there, you won't be able to have another 'w' to its right, and the last part, `str.charAt(i + 1) == 'w'` checks if the first letter to the right of the first occurrence of 'w' is another 'w'.

Comment: You could also just `return i > -1 && i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'w';`

Comment: Test case: `"awawwa"` now also fails (which is good). The OPs methods all fail on that one (false positive).

Comment: I *think* you could do `return i > -1 && i == str.indexOf("ww");`

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
private static boolean doubleX(String str) {
    if(str==null || str.length()<2) {
        return false;
    }
    int firstW = str.indexOf('w');
    String substr = str.substring(firstW, firstW+2);
    return "ww".equals(substr);
    
}
```

See also: https://attacomsian.com/blog/java-string-contains-substring

Comment: `"waawww"` should fail

Comment: You are almost there. Consider to compare the index of "ww" with the first index of "w" and you got it ...

Comment: you're still making it more difficult than it should be. just two times indexOf will do (as long as you keep in mind they can return -1, as has been pointed out in the comments)